# PHP PDO prepared statement string length limit

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem where the resulting prepared string is being limited in length:

My SQL statement goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO `empresa`
    (`nombre`, `calle`, `colonia`, `ciudad`, `estado`, `pais` `codigo_postal`, `telefono`, `email`)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And it doesn't matter if I bind the values using `bindParam()`, `bindValue()` or even at the `execute()`, it's always trimmed at a certain lenght and I get this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064

And it complains about…

> the right syntax to use near '`codigo_postal`, `telefono`, `email`) VALUES ('algo', '1', '7', 'b', 'ha' at line 2'

If I reduce the parameters in length, say, to make `'algo'` only `'al'`, the error is the same but `'ha'` is shown up to `'hasd'`, if I specify only one or two colums so the complete statement is shorter it's executed correctly. What can I do? A workaround is performing an `INSERT` and then *updating* its fields with another statements, but that's just silly.

Comment: the only limits on a statement length in mysql is `max_allowed_packet`. A statement cannot be split up into multiple parts, so it must be sent as a single monolithic string, and that length is whatever the server's `max_allowed_packet` setting is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
`pais` `codigo_postal`
```

You forgot comma.
Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `empresa`
    (`nombre`, `calle`, `colonia`, `ciudad`, `estado`, `pais`, `codigo_postal`, `telefono`, `email`)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Just one more thing: why does it complain until the values part and not right after the field name that's missing the comma?

Comment: It starts printing the query string from where the error exactly occured and you see the rest of the query too. :P

Comment: It could also say expecting "," comma... But it doesn't :P

Comment: Yes, that'd have saved me a very shameful question, oh well…

Comment: I didn't recieve any reputation from my answer, do you know why that is? It usually worths 10x5 + 15 = 65 Rep.

Comment: That's right, I don't know what happened, maybe an issue with the reputation system, sadly, no moderators take action on this usually. Maybe you topped for the 200 reputation limit per day? I can't see other user's rep from my cellphone

Comment: Is there a daily imit? :D I earned about 300 yesterday. ;) Thx for that info mate.